# Excel VBA Multiple Checkboxes to activate parts of code

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, togglebutton

The VBA code I am working on is currently updating six different Data Tables on one Worksheet in one go - it removes password protection, calculates the first Data Table, hardcodes the values and moves on to the next one, then locks it all again and says thank you.

The aim is to have a macro that would 'separate' the six parts of the code dealing with individual Data Tables in such a way that it only updates those Data Tables which have been selected by user, whilst retaining a single code (not individual subs for each option) and having the whole process activated by a single CommandButton.

To achieve this, apart from writing the actual code, I have created a UserForm and inserted six CheckBoxes and a single CommandButton, but got stuck at how to handle this further. How do I activate/disable parts of the code based on the boxes checked?

Comment: RE your mod flag: First of all, the receipt of an answer is not necessarily evidence that your question is clear or acceptable for our format. The answerer may have just guessed correctly. This question looks problematic to me, even in its current format, for at least two reasons: (1) it doesn't include a [mcve] that orients us to "what you have now", (2) it is almost certainly "too broad", since a good answer would have to explain the fundamentals of VBA programming to you, which is really more than we expect answers to do on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As far as why your edit after the question was placed "on hold" didn't lead to a re-opening... It actually did [put the question in the re-open queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16920148), where community members reviewed your edits and determined that they were not sufficient to motivate re-opening the question. As a moderator, I'm reluctant to override trusted community members, especially in light of my reservation the question is too broad. Normally, you could narrow it down a bit more, but that's going to be hard after getting an answer. This is why we try to close early.

Comment: Fair enough, I admit it is a pretty basic question and phrased in lay terms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in VBA there are event listeners. This can be seen in the upper part of the editor below the toolbars. Drop down to the left is the object. Drop down to the right is the event.

A quick way is to view the userform and double click the object. This will create a `Private Sub` for that object based on the action. So the code below is a userform with three Option Buttons. Same logic with yours just insert the code you need.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
MsgBox "1"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
MsgBox "2"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
MsgBox "3"
End Sub
```

Also you can check if the OptionButton is selected by checking its `.Value` property. And after checking run some code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    'Execute Code
ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    'Execute Code
Else
    'Execute Code
End If
End Sub
```

Code in Module1

```
Private Sub select_column_a()
    Range("A:A").Select
End Sub
```

Call inside another sub

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Module1.select_column_a
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that - in the process of trying it out. One thing though - the code is in Module 1, where at the beginning the whole Workbook is being unlocked, sheet by sheet, a couple of preparatory actions taken, and only then I want to bring in the UserForm with checkboxes and the CommandButton. Are you saying I should enter the whole code into the Private Sub of the Button? I was hoping to call the Userform on clicking a button on the sheet, select the options (check boxes), then have the CommandButrton activate the rest of the code, taking the values of the boxes into account.

Comment: Well you can keep a Private Sub in Module1 and call it within the Userform. Code will run or can be called regardless of it being Private or Sheets locked.

Comment: Also you can even name Subs the same name as long as they are in different Modules then call them with Module Name. Module1.subber and Module2.subber

Comment: added to the answer to show how calling is done

Answer (score 0):

@fscr Thank you again - works like a charm, with some additions, which is why I'm posting here for the benefit of other beginners like me.

In a CommandButton I inserted in the Sheet the sub is simply:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This shows my UserForm1 with all the checkboxes and one CommandButton saying "Go"

The Go Button (also CommandButton1 - no conflict there) has this inside:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
code
End Sub
```

where code is the name of my code (yes, I did...) stored in Module1 - it executes it smoothly without any separate calling function. Question here, might there be issues with backward compatibility? I'm working in Excel 2016 and learned that for instance ISFORMULA is new here and threw off issues on older machines.

Then the whole code kicks in with

```
Sub code()
UserForm1.Hide
```

followed by various actions, until it gets to my checkboxes, as suggested above (with ammendments):

```
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Calculating Sensitivities..."
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then

Range("A6:G15").Select
Selection.Table ColumnInput:=Range("AD3") 
Application.Calculate
Range("B7:G15").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ElseIf UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then

Range("AD17:AM26").Select
Selection.Table ColumnInput:=Range("AD2")
Application.Calculate
Range("AE18:AM26").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

etc.

The code executes the remaining options as checked, then comes End If and the rest of the code (cleaning up, locking the Sheets etc.) until

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlEnabled
End Sub
```

all without any errors. Thank you again!

Comment: The reason there is no conflict in Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() is because Module and Userform1 are in a different scope. You don't need to add Userform1.CommandButton because the Command Button is within the scope of the userform1. Just for added information.

Comment: Glad it helped!